# Changing specific strings into floats in multidimensional array

Tags: python-3.x

**I saved all the data into an array full of strings, but I want to change the strings in that array into float without changing the header (the first row) and first column of the array. How should I change my code?**

```
import numpy as np
import csv


with open('MI_5MINS_INDEX.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data=list(csv.reader(f))
    for line in data:
        line.remove('')
    ary=np.array(data)
    ary.astype(float)
```

Comment: This array is in 2d.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and it will work as you wish.